# How to use SQL group clause with FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED in Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, locking

How to use SQL group clause with FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED in Rails? I'd prefer to use ActiveRecord as opposed to raw queries. I have a generic model called `Job`, which has an attribute called `client_class`, which I'd like to group by. I also need to remove clients who exceed the limits set in the class variable `CLIENT_LIMITS`. My setup is as follows:

```rb
CLIENT_LIMITS = { CLIENT_1: 2, CLIENT_2: 3, ... }.freeze

unavailable_clients = Job.running
  .group(:client_class)
  .count
  .select { |k, v| v >= CLIENT_LIMITS[k] }
  .keys

job = Job.lock("FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED")
  .queued
  .where.not(client_class: unavailable_clients)
  .sample
```

I get the following error:

```
.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:672:in `exec_params': PG::FeatureNotSupported: ERROR:  FOR UPDATE is not allowed with GROUP BY clause (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)

.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:672:in `exec_params': ERROR:  FOR UPDATE is not allowed with GROUP BY clause (PG::FeatureNotSupported)
```